# Send emails from Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, mail-server

I have a web server with Django, hosted with Apache server. I would like to configure Google App Engine for the email server. My web server should be able to use Google App Engine, when it makes any email send using EmailMessage or sendmail infrastructure of Google Mail API.

I learnt that by using Remote API, I can access Google App Engine server from my main web server. However, I could not access the Mail APIs supported by Google App Engine.

Is the Remote API strictly for Datastore? If so, can only the DB read from it and no other API calls can?

Comment: Can anyone help me with a snippet which can send an email with google appengine using remote api from a different server?? If not mail, any api call from Google appengine will do.

Answer (score 2):

The example code for the remote APi gives you an interactive console from which you can access *any* of the modules in your application. I see no requirement that they be only datastore operations.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a third-party SMTP relaying service. [Here's a list](http://www.birds-eye.net/article_archive/smtp_mail_relay_services.htm).

Most of them have a simple API that lets you forward your email to their service. That way, you're not bound by the AppEngine's limits. The more reputable ones also take care of headers necessary so your app isn't tagged as a spam sender (which hopefully, it isn't :-)